# object closed when retrieving blob content from h2 using slick3 h2 driver

Tags: h2, slick

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-166]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:135)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1383)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1361)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBlob.checkClosed(JdbcBlob.java:317)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBlob.length(JdbcBlob.java:54)
```

this happened when I upgraded my slick from 2 to 3 and doing the migration. H2 version itself didn't change. on slick2 the code works fine.

this happened when I first retrieve the blob row record from database using **slick** `db.run` and then transforming the blob into some text data [tried both stream & bytes].

it seems to me that, the blob is not able to get back the connections etc...

what is the correct way to pull the blob data out and transform into text using slick3 h2 driver ?

Comment: So, it looks like the connection is already closed, and after that, you try to get the length of a blob. You should close the connection afterwards, not before. Also, you might want to upgrade H2, the version you are using is quite old (1.3.166)

Comment: the issue is about the connection is closed. the problem is now the connection/session is handled by slick3 driver now. asynchronously.  how to explicitly manage the connection is the issue.